# Checking a string to see if its blank

Tags: javascript, html

```
if($(this).find("Dimension1").text()) is blank
display nothing
else if ($(this).find("Dimension1").text()) has a value
put a "x" before printing $(this).find("Dimension1").text()
```

so it will be "x" + Dimension1

how do i write that in javascript

Comment: Welcome SO. When you ask a question you need to accept an appropriate answer for it. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) section for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str= $(this).find("Dimension1").text();
if (str!="")
str = "x"+str;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var textval = $(this).find("Dimension1").text(); 
if(textval =="") 
{
           // your code
}
else
{
               //apend code if nto blank
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.trim()` function of jQuery for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If a text is blank in JavaScript, the `.length` function will give you 0.

```
if($(this).find("Dimension1").text().length == 0){
    // do nothing
}
else {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`text()` is falsy, which means that you can just do:

```
if (!$(this).text()) {
    // Code
} else {
    // Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem

```
var str=$(this).find("Dimension1").text();
     if(str.length =="0" ){
           str=" ";
        }
        else {
        str="x"+str;
                   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = $(this).find('ur_selector').text().trim();
if(data == '')
{
  //logic here
}
 else
 {
   //logic here
  }
```

Note : `.find()` accepts selectors like `class,id,DOM element`

Answer (score 1):

In pure Javascript (I don't know what `text()` returns, so I check type at first):

```
var s = $(this).find("Dimension1").text();

if (typeof s === "string" && s.length > 0) {
   s = "x" + s;
}
```

However there are many other solutions. For example Prototype.js defines `blank()` and `empty()` functions for String. I am sure jQuery does the same.